# Convert string input into integer list in just one line of code in python

Tags: python

input comma separated numbers, convert them into integer from string and then into integer list. this is what i came up with. is there any other way?

```
x = list(map(lambda x : int(x),(input()).split(",")))

print(x)
```

input : `1,2,3,55,66,714,78`

output : `[1, 2, 3, 55, 66, 714, 78]`

Comment: As your code works, I would suggest this may belong on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: However, I would also suggest: `list(map(int, input.split(',')))`

Comment: As alluded to by @Chris, the `lambda` is not needed as `map` maps each element in the list to `int`. So answer your question, yes - there are many ways.  But this is generally the most efficient.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: However, the `input` function needs to be called, for `split` to work; so it’ll be: `list(map(int, input().split(',')))`

Comment: Thanks for catching my late night oops missing the `()`.

Answer (score 4):

there's also list comprehension

```py
[int(n) for n in input().split(",")]
```

Comment: List comprehension would be slightly faster than list(map())

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a tuple, you can use `eval`

```
eval(input())
1,2,3,55,66,714,78

(1, 2, 3, 55, 66, 714, 78)
```